# Per Parent Node Grouping in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The title of the question might be confusing. If anyone has the correct terminology for this , please edit.
I have an XML input file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="show.xsl"?>
    <patients>
        <patient>
            <name>Joe</name>
            <age>45</age>
            <kids>
                <kid>
                    <name>Ramsay</name>
                    <gender>M</gender>
                </kid>
                <kid>
                    <name>Eva</name>
                    <gender>F</gender>
                </kid>
                <kid>
                    <name>Arthas</name>
                    <gender>M</gender>
                </kid>
            </kids>
        </patient>
        <patient>
            <name>Adam</name>
            <age>34</age>
            <kids>
                <kid>
                    <name>Jon</name>
                    <gender>M</gender>
                </kid>
                <kid>
                    <name>Jane</name>
                    <gender>F</gender>
                </kid>
                <kid>
                    <name>Sunita</name>
                    <gender>F</gender>
                </kid>
            </kids>
        </patient>
    </patients>
```

I want to get an output similar to this:

```
    Name: Joe
    Age: 45
    Kids:
        Boys:
            Ramsay
            Arthas
        Girls:
            Eva
    Name: Adam
    Age: 34
    Kids:
        Boys:
            Jon
        Girls:
            Jane
            Sunita
```

Here is the XSLT I wrote using xsl:key but it gives wrong output as it can't group patient-wise.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="header" match="//kid" use="gender"/>
<xsl:template match="//patients/patient">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
        <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">Boys:
            </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('header', 'M')">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
            </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
        </xsl:text>        
<xsl:text xml:space="preserve">Girls:
            </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('header', 'F')">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
            </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looking for a solution preferably in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Doesn't your data include a unique id for the patient?

Comment: You could consider name as a unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data doesn't have a unique patient id (or even if it has), you can use the generate-id() function to produce one. I am not sure if you do have one (normally, a name cannot be presumed to be unique), so try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kids-by-gender" match="kid" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::patient), gender)"/>

<xsl:template match="patient">
    <xsl:variable name="pid" select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Name: ', name, '&#10;') "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Age: ', age, '&#10;') "/>
    <xsl:text>Kids:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#9;Boys:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kids-by-gender', concat($pid, 'M')) "/>
    <xsl:text>&#9;Girls:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kids-by-gender', concat($pid, 'F')) "/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kid">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#9;&#9;', name, '&#10;') "/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this needs more work to accommodate patients with no children of either sex, or no children at all.